# Android - How to work with 2 'values' folders for strings in 2 languages?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I plan on making my app bilingual, English and German.
I have two folder within `/values` for both, and now all of a sudden none of my strings can be found, giving me the following error for all my strings

```
"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/stringname')
```

How can I tell it to look in my new folders where all the strings are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need 2 folders inside `values`. In `values` you keep your `strings.xml` file (from here it will take the strings for english) and you create another folder, inside `res/` called `values-de` where you will create a copy of the `strings.xml` file and just translate the content. The android system will choose the right content, depending on the language used on the phone.